# Mapster not mapping entire object, with a read only property with return type as an interface

Tags: c#, .net

Mapster not mapping entire object, with a read only property with return type as an interface.

Seems to be effecting level 2, that is one down in object graph. For example Order.OrderItems[0], here OrderItem instance is created and added to collection but no properties are mapped.

OrderItem.Product is readonly and returns an interface, example

```
interface IOrderItem{
  //other props
  //this causes Mapster to ignore all mappings
  IProduct OrderItem.Product {get;}
}
```

**Example**

```
public interface IOrderItemMutable
{
   long Id { get; set; }
   int Quantity { get; set; }
   long? ProductId { get; set; }
   long? OrderId { get; set; }
   string? Notes { get; set; }
   [AdaptIgnore]
   IProduct Product { get; }
}
```

#### PocoStuff

```
#define PChildCollectionIsReadOnly
//#define PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl
//#define PProductIsMutable
#define PProductEnabled

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mapster;


namespace TheTechZap.SharedDemos.Main.MapsterTrial1.Tests.Main.AppCode.Pocos
{

    public class ZDataMemberAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    public class OrderMutableDto
    {
        readonly Lazy<IList<OrderItemMutableDto>> _orderItems;
        public OrderMutableDto() => _orderItems = new Lazy<IList<OrderItemMutableDto>>(new List<OrderItemMutableDto>(100));
        public DateTime BookedOn { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public long CustomerId { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

        [UseDestinationValue]
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public IList<OrderItemMutableDto> OrderItems => _orderItems.Value;
    }

    public interface IOrderMutableLocalNoBase
    {
        DateTime BookedOn { get; set; }
        long CustomerId { get; set; }
        string? Notes { get; set; }
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        [UseDestinationValue]
#if (PChildCollectionIsReadOnly && PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl)
      IList<OrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; }
#elif (PChildCollectionIsReadOnly && !PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl)
        IList<IOrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; }
#else
   IList<IOrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; set; }
#endif
    }

    public class OrderMutableLocalNoBase : IOrderMutableLocalNoBase
    {
        public DateTime BookedOn { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public long CustomerId { get; set; }

        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

        [UseDestinationValue]
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
#if (PChildCollectionIsReadOnly && PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl)
      public IList<OrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; } = new List<OrderItemMutable>();
#elif (PChildCollectionIsReadOnly && !PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl)
        public IList<IOrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; } = new List<IOrderItemMutable>();
#else
   public IList<IOrderItemMutable> OrderItems { get; set; } = new List<IOrderItemMutable>();
#endif

#if (PProductEnabled)
        [UseDestinationValue]
        public IProduct? Product { get; set; }
#endif
    }
    public interface IHasProduct
    {
        IProduct? Product { get; }
    }

    public interface IOrderItemMutable //: IHasProduct
    {
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        long Id { get; set; }

        int Quantity { get; set; }
        long? ProductId { get; set; }
        long? OrderId { get; set; }
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        string? Notes { get; set; }
#if (PProductEnabled)
        [UseDestinationValue]
        IProduct? Product
        {
            get;
#if PProductIsMutable
      set;
#endif

        }
#endif
    }

    public class OrderItemMutable : IOrderItemMutable
    {
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

        public long? OrderId { get; set; }
        public long? ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
#if (PProductEnabled)
        [UseDestinationValue]
        public IProduct? Product { get; set; }
#endif
    }

    public class IProduct
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItemMutableDto
    {
        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ZDataMemberAttribute]
        public string? Notes { get; set; }

        public long? OrderId { get; set; }
        public long? ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Test stuff

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using LINQPad;
using Mapster;
using TheTechZap.SharedDemos.Main.MapsterTrial1.Tests.Main.AppCode.Pocos;
using Xunit;

namespace TheTechZap.SharedDemos.Main.MapsterTrial1.Tests.Main
{

    public class MainTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///    Mapping from concrete to interface problems with child collections, solutions:
        ///    1. Must provide ConstructUsing(), so Mapster knows which type to create.
        ///    2. Child collections, readonly set. Mapster will fail on mapping whole class. Add `[UseDestinationValue]' attribute
        ///    to concrete class.
        ///    3. use the explicit Adapt method, that DOES NOT accept type params, `Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt(dto, entity,
        ///    dto.GetType(), entity.GetType());`. Mapster used the Type params, an interface, to define destination type, problems
        ///    Indicates whether or not the specified type is a list.
        ///    Problems:
        /// </summary>
        public void BuildMapsterConfig(bool strict = true)
        {
            //Do explicit mapping, for debugging
            if (strict)
                TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.RequireExplicitMapping = true;
            //TypeAdapterConfig<OrderMutableDto, OrderMutableDto>.NewConfig().TwoWays();
            //TypeAdapterConfig<IOrderMutableLocalNoBase, OrderMutableDto>.NewConfig().TwoWays();
            //TypeAdapterConfig<OrderMutableDto, OrderMutableLocalNoBase>.NewConfig().TwoWays();
            TypeAdapterConfig<OrderMutableDto, OrderMutableLocalNoBase>.NewConfig().ConstructUsing(src => new OrderMutableLocalNoBase());
            TypeAdapterConfig<OrderMutableDto, IOrderMutableLocalNoBase>.NewConfig().ConstructUsing(src => new OrderMutableLocalNoBase());
            TypeAdapterConfig<OrderItemMutableDto, IOrderItemMutable>.NewConfig().ConstructUsing(src => new OrderItemMutable());
            //TypeAdapterConfig<IOrderItemMutable, OrderItemMutable>.NewConfig().ConstructUsing(src => new OrderItemMutable());
            //TypeAdapterConfig<IOrderMutableLocalNoBase, OrderMutableDto>.NewConfig().ConstructUsing(src => new OrderMutableDto());

            TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.IncludeMember((member, side) => member.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ZDataMemberAttribute>().Any());
            TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.IgnoreMember((member, side) => !member.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ZDataMemberAttribute>().Any());

            if (strict) TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Compile();
        }

        /*
         in the poco class file compile constants will cause test to fail:

     #define PChildCollectionIsReadOnly
     //#define PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl
     //#define PProductIsMutable
     #define PProductEnabled

     for success:
     #define PChildCollectionIsReadOnly
     //#define PChildCollectionIsTypedImpl
     //#define PProductIsMutable
     //#define PProductEnabled

     Fix why this causes error: OrderItem and IOrderItem contain:
     IProduct Product {get;set;}

     We do not need to map Product, it should be ignored
     */
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(true, true, "target is var of type interface")]
        [InlineData(false, true, "target is var of type interface")]
        [InlineData(true, false, "target is var of type impl")]
        [InlineData(false, false, "target is var of type impl")]
        public void Test_domain_dto_to_entity_using_raw_mapster_debug_with_local_entity_class_attempt_to_fix(bool mappingStrict, bool targetIsInterface, string name)
        {
            BuildMapsterConfig(mappingStrict);

            //IOrderMutableLocal entity = new OrderMutableLocal(new FluentValidationBusinessRuleManager<IOrderMutableLocal>(null));
            IOrderMutableLocalNoBase entityCommon;

            IOrderMutableLocalNoBase entityAsInterface = null;
            OrderMutableLocalNoBase entityAsImpl = null;
            if (targetIsInterface) entityAsInterface = new OrderMutableLocalNoBase();
            else entityAsImpl = new OrderMutableLocalNoBase();

            entityCommon = targetIsInterface ? entityAsInterface : entityAsImpl;

            OrderMutableDto dto = new() { CustomerId = 987, Notes = "some notes here...", BookedOn = new DateTime(2001, 02, 03, 4, 5, 6) };
            OrderMutableDto dto2 = new();
            dto.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItemMutableDto { Id = 1, Notes = "1", Quantity = 1 });
            dto.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItemMutableDto { Id = 2, Notes = "2", Quantity = 2 });

            entityCommon.Dump("entity - before");
            dto.Dump("dto - before");

            entityCommon.Should().NotBeNull();
            dto.Should().NotBeNull();

            if (targetIsInterface) dto.Adapt(entityAsInterface, dto.GetType(), entityAsInterface.GetType());
            else dto.Adapt(entityAsImpl);

            //dto.Adapt(dto2);

            entityCommon.Dump("entity - after");
            dto.Dump("dto - after");

            entityCommon.CustomerId.Should().Be(dto.CustomerId);
            entityCommon.Notes.Should().Be(dto.Notes);
            entityCommon.OrderItems.Should().HaveCount(2);
            entityCommon.OrderItems.Should().AllBeOfType<OrderItemMutable>().And.AllBeAssignableTo<IOrderItemMutable>();
            entityCommon.OrderItems.Select(i => i.Id).Should().Equal(1, 2);
            entityCommon.OrderItems.Select(i => i.Notes).Should().Equal("1", "2");
        }
        [Fact]
        public void Test_ping() { }
    }
}
```

Mapping from concrete to interface problems with child collections, solutions:

1. Must provide ConstructUsing(), so Mapster knows which type to create.
2. Child collections, readonly set. Mapster will fail on mapping whole class. Add `[UseDestinationValue]' attribute to concrete class.
3. use the explicit Adapt method, that DOES NOT accept type params, `Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt(dto, entity, dto.GetType(), entity.GetType());`. Mapster used the Type params, an interface, to define destination type, problems Indicates whether or not the specified type is a list.